# Jquery/Javascript: Display a random image from an array by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var images = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Playing_card_heart_5.svg/200px-Playing_card_heart_5.svg.png", "http://www.pandasecurity.com/mediacenter/src/uploads/2014/11/short-link.jpg", ];

function myFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length); $('#afbeelding').attr('src', images[x]);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<img id="afbeelding">
```

Comment: Please state a specific question and supply a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It doesn't show anything, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible causes of this problem, but the most likely is that you may not have installed JQuery. In fact, you don't even need JQuery for this:

```
var images = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Playing_card_heart_5.svg/200px-Playing_card_heart_5.svg.png", "http://www.pandasecurity.com/mediacenter/src/uploads/2014/11/short-link.jpg"];

function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length));
        document.getElementById('afbeelding').src = images[x];
    }
```

Note: Untested.
Also, you had a null entry at the end of your array, so I fixed that.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. : ) Please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Done! (I think, I'm just new here so doesn't really know how everything works :) )

Answer (score 0):

Look at this plunker I made with your code. By the way one ")" was missing after images.length
https://plnkr.co/edit/mdyXsf5FoSPHOQGqCoO2?p=preview

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length)); $('#afbeelding').attr('src', images[x]);
```

Tell me if it's ok